# Phoenix live reload breaks on compilation error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Occasionally, when I make a typo in my Elixir code and a `CompileError` happens, Phoenix refuses to live-reload even once I've fixed everything, and keeps printing `App.Endpoint.path/1 is undefined` (`App` is my app). Of course, the Endpoint *is* defined perfectly fine and works again as soon as I restart `mix phoenix.server`.

As far as I know, I'm on the latest version of everything. Since I can't find anything about this error online, I suspect I've misconfigured something, and I'm grateful for your suggestions on how to trace down the root of this.

```
[info] Sent 200 in 200ms
iex[debug] Live reload: web/resolver/reviewer.ex
[debug] Live reload: web/resolver/reviewer.ex
Compiling 20 files (.ex)

== Compilation error on file web/resolver/reviewer.ex ==
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) unbound variable `f` in query
    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.preload/3
    (app) web/resolver/reviewer.ex:519: App.Resolver.Reviewer.sc_data/1
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.|>/2
    (app) web/resolver/reviewer.ex:520: App.Resolver.Reviewer.sc_data/1
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:116: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1

[error] #PID<0.2279.0> running App.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET /reviewers/2016/1234
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function App.Endpoint.path/1 is undefined (module App.Endpoint is not available)
        (app) App.Endpoint.path("/phoenix/live_reload/frame")
        (phoenix_live_reload) lib/phoenix_live_reload/live_reloader.ex:115: Phoenix.LiveReloader.reload_assets_tag/1
        (phoenix_live_reload) lib/phoenix_live_reload/live_reloader.ex:97: anonymous fn/1 in Phoenix.LiveReloader.before_send_inject_reloader/1
        (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1623: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
        (plug) lib/plug/conn.ex:909: Plug.Conn.run_before_send/2
        (plug) lib/plug/conn.ex:355: Plug.Conn.send_resp/1
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/code_reloader.ex:50: Phoenix.CodeReloader.call/2
        (app) lib/app/endpoint.ex:1: App.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
        (app) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: App.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (app) lib/app/endpoint.ex:1: App.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
[error] Ranch protocol #PID<0.2281.0> (:cowboy_protocol) of listener App.Endpoint.HTTP terminated
** (exit) killed
Compiling 20 files (.ex)

== Compilation error on file web/resolver/reviewer.ex ==
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) unbound variable `f` in query
    (ecto) expanding macro: Ecto.Query.preload/3
    (app) web/resolver/reviewer.ex:519: App.Resolver.Reviewer.sc_data/1
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.|>/2
    (app) web/resolver/reviewer.ex:520: App.Resolver.Reviewer.sc_data/1
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:116: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1

^C
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
```

Comment: Maybe to be completely sure, that your endpoint is fine, just attach it.

Comment: Okay, so the endpoint seems to be actually dead. I occasionally get `** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function App.Endpoint.call/2 is undefined (module App.Endpoint is not available)` as well. How can an endpoint just die and not get restarted by the supervisor?

Comment: Is your endpoint uses `Phoenix.endpoint` or did you change the name of your app recently and didn't change in endpoint as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Phoenix's live reload functionality is part of the `Endpoint`, so once the latter crashes, code reload doesn't work anymore.

It is possible to crash the Endpoint by inserting errors in code that falls under the Endpoint, e.g. by adding `plug :some_imaginary_plug` or by causing syntax errors in `router.ex`, since the router is also plugged into the Endpoint.

Now, it turns out that I was using the [Absinthe](https://github.com/absinthe-graphql/absinthe) package by `forward`-ing all `/graphql` requests to the Absinthe plug directly. As a result, any GraphQL type definition and related `resolver` functions (which happen to make up most of my app) are fragile: any inconspicuous `CompileError` due to them indirectly (but inevitably) leads the Endpoint to crash.

The best workaround I have found – until the Absinthe devs manage to make the resolvers independent from the type defs, which they have suggested they will – is to start the server with `iex -S mix phoenix.server`, and to manually run `recompile` whenever the Endpoint crashes. While this doesn't fix the underlying problem of the CodeReloader being a part of the Endpoint instead of vice versa, it keeps me from having to re-run webpack everytime, which is the biggest pain point.

Comment: Hey, thanks for digging into it. I suppose this is your issue for Phoenix: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1845
Did this ever get resolved? Is there a ticket in either Phoenix or Absinthe that I could track? Is manually running `recompile` still the best thing to do?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply – I don't remember what happened to this in the end but I haven't seen this error in a long time so I assume Absinthe devs have fixed it?